# Merge multiple rows in column SQL SERVER without temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have following result set that i am creating by query.

```
ID | Name | CRAmount | DRAmount
1  | ABC  | 50000    | NULL
1  | ABC  | NULL     | 10000
1  | ABC  | 5000     | NULL
1  | ABC  | 6000     | NULL
1  | ABC  | NULL     | 7000
```

I want the result like

```
ID | Name | CRAmount | DRAmount
1  | ABC  | 61000    | 17000
```

I know i can do that by using temporary table but i want simple method to do.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [SUM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want simple aggregation:

```
select id, name, sum(cramount) cramount, sum(dramount) dramount
from mytable
group by id, name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ID, Name, SUM(CRAmount) as CRAmount, SUM(DRAmount) as DRAmount
FROM TableName 
GROUP BY ID, Name;
GO
```

Comment: You forgot to add ID on the group by section

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID , [Name] , SUM(ISNULL(CRAmount,0))CRAmount,SUM(ISNULL(DRAmount,0))DRAmount FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY ID , [Name]
```